# Bootable XP CD from iso.img file

Tags: bootable-media, iso-image

I've got a downloaded version of windows XP as an iso.img file.  How do i turn this into a disk i can boot from?

Edit - I've downloaded this from MSDN site.  It's a .img file and I'm trying to install this on Microsoft Virtual PC 2007 for a developer environment.

Comment: It should already be bootable. Have you set your BIOS to look for bootable media in the optical drive?

Comment: Thanks for replying.

Yep i've got CD Drive top of the BIOS Boot list.

I get

"CLIENT MAC ADDR: 00 03...
DHCP..../ (works for a few minutes, then....)
No DHCP or ProxyDHCP offers were recieved (or)
No boot filename recieved"

Then on a new screen

"reboot and select proper boot device or insert boot media in selected boot device"

Any ideas?  Thanks.

Comment: Update: gave trying up on Microsoft Virtual PC and tried the .iso file on VMWare Fusion - worked perfectly 1st time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to burn the .iso from a burning tool that can burn .iso files. Then, as ChrisF mentionned, check your boot sequence config in your BIOS. If the .iso file is valid and bootable, you should be able to install XP

Answer (score 0):

You can burn it to a CD using something like ImgBurn (XP and Vista) or Windows 7's built in disc burner, or Brasero on Linux. 
If it's a .img file, [this](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/FromImgFiles) Ubuntu guide should help. Just substitute the ubuntu ISO with your XP ISO.

Comment: Have burned it to CD with ImgBurn but it still won't boot from this.

Tried the Win32 Disk Imager too but that wouldn't even get going - got a device error